# Write response requests on logs with Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, logging

**!UPDATE!**

Big thank's to @ivan

default.conf:

```
log_format include_id '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request_id "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/key.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://sns-mock:9911;
        proxy_store /var/log/nginx/requests/mohsin.json;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  sns-mock:
    image: s12v/sns
    container_name: sns-mock
    ports:
      - "9911:9911"
    networks:
      - default-nw
    volumes:
      - ./config/db.json:/etc/sns/db.json

  sns-mock-proxy:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: sns-mock-proxy
    ports:
      - "8443:443"
    networks:
      - default-nw
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      - ./log/nginx/requests:/var/log/nginx/requests
    depends_on:
      - sns-mock

networks:
  default-nw:
    external: true
```

Php test file:

```
<?php

use Aws\Result;
use Aws\Sns\SnsClient;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class FooTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testFoo()
    {
        $snsClient = new SnsClient([
            'endpoint' => 'localhost:8443',
            'region' => 'eu-west-2',
            'version' => 'latest'
        ]);

        $result = $snsClient->publish([
            'Message' => 'foo',
            'TopicArn' => 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:123450000001:test-topic'
        ]);

        dd($result, 'ok');
    }
}
```

Test result:

[image]

My project:

[image]

On my access.log file, i can catch response from phpunit test like here:

```
172.28.0.1 - - [23/May/2022:06:54:04 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 270 "-" "aws-sdk-php/3.222.17 OS/Linux/5.13.0-41-generic lang/php/8.1.6 GuzzleHttp/7" "-"
```

===================================================================================================================================

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general answer to your question is "No". However some kind of workaround is possible.

Every request gets processed by nginx receives some internal request ID available via the [`$request_id`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_id) variable (16 random bytes, in hexadecimal). You can add that ID to your access log defining your own custom log format:

```
log_format include_id '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request_id "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log include_id;
```

Next, in the same location where you have your `proxy_pass` directive add the [`proxy_store`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_store) one:

```
proxy_store /var/log/nginx/requests/$request_id.json;
```

I use the separate `/var/log/nginx/requests` directory here to not make your `/var/log/nginx` turning into a mess. Of course it should be created manually before you start the docker container, and it should be writable the same way as `/var/log/nginx` itself (including such a things as SELinux context, if being used on the host system). However for the testing purposes you can start with the `proxy_store /var/log/nginx/$request_id.json;`.

The whole nginx config should look like

```
log_format include_id '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request_id "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log include_id;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/key.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://sns-mock:9911;
        proxy_store /var/log/nginx/requests/$request_id.json;
    }
}
```

If you want requests to be available via the plain HTTP protocol too, you can use the same configuration for the plain HTTP server block instead of the one you've shown in your question:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log include_id;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://sns-mock:9911;
        proxy_store /var/log/nginx/requests/$request_id.json;
    }
}
```

or issue an HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect instead:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 308 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Now the response body for each request which can be identified from the access log via its request ID, something like

```
172.18.0.1 - - [20/May/2022:19:54:14 +0000] d6010d713b2dce3cd2713f1ea178e140 "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "aws-sdk-php/3.222.17 OS/Linux/5.13.0-41-generic lang/php/8.1.6 GuzzleHttp/7" "-"
```

will be available under the `/var/log/nginx/requests` directory (response body for the request shown in the given access log entry will be available as `d6010d713b2dce3cd2713f1ea178e140.json` file).

Comment: Thank's
Now, I correctly have request_id on my access.log file but, no request folder is created on my docker container in /var/log/nginx/.
Does the error come from my docker-compose.yml?
  `sns-mock-proxy:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: sns-mock-proxy
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - api
    volumes:
      - ./config/proxy_ssl.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./log/nginx:/var/log/nginx`

Comment: I edited my nginx file conf

Comment: This is not a configuration that could respond to the `POST` request with a JSON response. It does not contain any part that can proxy incoming request to the `sns-mock` container, it can only respond with some static content from the `/usr/share/nginx/html` folder. I assume you are trying to use some kind of configuration described [here](https://medium.com/@chewcysg/running-a-local-instance-of-aws-sns-4df9893b2e59), and that one is clear and uses the `proxy_pass` to communicate with the `sns-mock` container. The `proxy_store` directive makes no sense without the `proxy_pass` one.

Comment: Please post your real `docker-compose.yml` and your real `./config/proxy_ssl.conf` nginx config.

Comment: Hello @ivan

Yes, is that tutorial, my need it's to test a message publishing on Sns topic

I update my principal post

Comment: Thank's again, i have this error now:

`2022/05/21 11:10:50 [crit] 32#32: *3 open() "/var/log/nginx/requests/eec3ca72eec3d712d470dfc421ab357f.json.0000000004" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 172.28.0.1, server: , request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.28.0.2:9911/", host: "localhost:8443"`

He tried to write a file with number on end of name :/

I hade permission on docker-compose.yml like this :
- ./log/requests:/var/log/nginx/requests

Comment: It's ok with right permission
thank's a lot :)

Comment: Just, i don't know why my json files are emtpy
Maybe SnsClient do not return a response

Comment: I don't know what can be wrong with SnsClient, but I think the nginx part (which is about the question is) should be ok. Maybe you need to make sure the SnsClient responds properly querying it directly via 9911 TCP port before putting nginx reverse proxy in front of it.

Comment: I understand why, maybe because of the rights of the json file.
On my docker-container, the json files are always created in read-only.
On my unit test, do you know how can i test a custom response just to see if the response set on json files please ?
I update my post
Thank's again